# Jekyll and Strapi: The Strapi server sent a error with the following status: 404. Please make sure it is correctly running

Tags: jekyll, strapi

I am currently trying to follow this tutorial (https://blog.strapi.io/building-a-static-website-using-jekyll-and-strapi/) and everything was working fine until the "Posts List" step. Once I added the _layouts/home.html file, changed _config.yml  and restarted the jekyll server (bundle exec jekyll serve), I ended up with an error message:

> jekyll 3.8.5 | Error: The Strapi server sent a error with the following status: 404. Please make sure it is correctly running.

Thing is, the strapi server IS RUNNING... I have access to the the strapi admin backend and I can access and view the Posts json object by visiting: http://localhost:1337/posts.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have data in your `Post` content type.
Create some posts and then retry.